# Generate a descriptor YAML/JSON from an existing javascript code

Tags: javascript, node.js, swagger, codegen

I would need to have the chance to generate a descriptor of an existing service.
The service is a REST API, written in javascript.

No tools, library, or framework were used to generate that API, like Swagger for example.
The code was written manually, it exists, it works, the descriptor is currently a YAML file, also written manually.This means that, sometimes, meanwhile developments are done, code and descriptors could be misaligned in some way, it's a risk.

Since we want to connect different clients to the same service, and we want to be able to automate client generation, we want to investigate if there is a tool we can use to generate the descriptor file from the existing code, and not viceversa.

Summarizing the use case:

- server side existing, written in JS, it implements a REST API
- we want to generate a descriptor from that code
- after we'll use the descriptor to generate client/s

Is that possible?
I know that swagger-codegen can be used to generate client and server, starting from a descriptor, but this is not our use case.

Thanks for who has an experience on a similar issue.